# iOS Keyboard & Arrow Keys

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard, ios

Running the iOS 9.2.1 on an iPhone 6S and an iPad 4 Mini, I notice that the iPhone keyboard in landscape mode now includes left & right arrow keys (how long, I wonder?). This does not appear to be the case in the iPad, even though you would expect that they would fit more easily there.

Is there a way I can get these arrow keys for the landscape orientation or for the iPad?

(I don’t mean on specialised keyboards in some apps, but on the standard keyboard).

Thanks

Comment: If you find a third party keyboard which has arrow keys, it should work in all apps (at least if if it requires iOS 8 or later).

Answer (score 5):

With the iPads, you can hold two fingers on the keyboard and move the cursor around by moving your two fingers around.

Additionally, you can double tap you fingers on the keyboard and it will select current word. If you double tap but keep your fingers down on the screen on the second tap, you can use this to select text by cursor position.

On the iPhone 6S, you can actually hard press (3D touch) to move the cursor, rather than using arrow keys in landscape.

Answer (score 1):

You can swipe with two fingers on the keyboard to move the cursor around. It's even easier to use than arrow keys.

Comment: I know it has been awhile since the last post but swiping with two fingers to move the curser does not work on my iPod touch 9.3.5 but it does work on my iPad 9.3.5.

Answer (score 1):

This does not help when using applications that use the arrow keys to perform functions.  The only reason I am interested in these keys is to retrieve a previous command in a comman line application.  There is no way to use this frequently used function from my iPad so I have to lug around my MacBook or a PC in order to do my job remotely.